# Javascript point to Folder: Solution and Tool

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript

We are updating our store to **Magento 1.9.2** and we are in the testing phase. The store is using Ultimo theme.

On all product pages there is a error in the header, which refers to the following line:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://www.mystore.com/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/">
 </script>
```

The JavaScript is pointing to a folder, not to a file.
So the file cannot be found and trying to access the folder return a "**403 Forbidden**" error

First question: how can we solve it?

The second (and more interesting): is there a way/tool to understand which part of Magento – plug-in, theme, core, other – is generating that line?

Comment: go for ultimo's layout files updated by you

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: you just need to add a search in files for layout folder of ultimo theme for `frontend/ultimo/default`.
And for second I must say there is no such tool that can help you for troubleshooting these kind of errors, but in magento it self there is a feature of template hint that can help you alot in future. And after working on more and more projects of magento you will have enough skill and knowledge to find it.